# How to get the node and Source node jQuery dynatree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynatree, jquery-dynatree

I am trying drag and drop option with jquery dynatree. Here upon drop of a node on another node I have to perform some db operation so I can call a function which makes ajax call. The problem I am facing is how to get `node` and `source node` when I write a function for `onDrop` option. Here is my `dnd` of dynatree,

```
 dnd: {
      preventVoidMoves: true, // Prevent dropping nodes 'before self', etc.
      onDragStart: function(node) {
        return true;
      },
      onDragEnter: function(node, sourceNode) {

        if(node.parent !== sourceNode.parent)
          return true;
        return ["before", "after"];
      },
      onDrop: function(node, sourceNode, hitMode, ui, draggable) {
         alert("moved Node: "+node+"  SourceNode:"+sourceNode);
        sourceNode.move(node, hitMode);
      }
    }
```

The alert in `onDrop` displays like this ,

> Moved Node: DynatreeNode :'default'
>       SourceNode: DynatreeNode <123>: '123'

Here I want just values `default` and `123`. How can I get that ?

Answer (score 0):

to get the key do:

> var value = sourceNode.data.key;

basically if you want access to the node options, just use node.data.optionyouwant

see: [Node Options](http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/dynatree-doc.html#nodeOptions)